# Update correctly the fields of the json file for REST API

Tags: python, json, rest

I am retrieving a json file with REST API using a GET in python and want to retrieve the json file update some values of it and then update that value. My get is the following:

```
 r1 = requests.get(url)
```

It returns the whole json file. Now I want to update some values of the json and put it back using PUT REST API call. My put command is the following:

```
requests.put(url, json=r1)
```

The fields I want to update are the following:

```
r1.json()['a']['a'] = 2 // print r1.json()['a']['a'] ->1
r1.json()['a']['b'] = 2 // print r1.json()['a']['b'] ->1
r1.json()['a']['c'] = 2 // print r1.json()['a']['c'] ->1
```

My question is how can I update correctly the fields of my json?

Comment: U call to json() from response and u cant change it. First you need save r1.json to some variable and then change some values and use it in requests.put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save it as a variable, modify it and then send it back

```
my_json = r1.json()
my_json['a']['a'] = 2
my_json['a']['b'] = 2
my_json['a']['c'] = 2
requests.put(url, json=my_json)
```

What you are doing in your code essentialy, is calling `.json()` which generates a dictionary from the response, you are not really modifying the response object - but really modifying the result of the returned value from the `.json()` call.

Comment: This did the trick. However, am having another quetsion. If I want just to update the value of the json and not to create a new should I do a put or a post? The json file it is changed properly but then the put does not change the field in my server.

Comment: Usually, to update some resource PUT is used, POST is used for creation. But in fact, you can make anything using POST, it depends on your app architecture and preferences. 

[Description of meaning HTTP method in terms of REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) -> Relationship between URL and HTTP methods

Comment: "which generates a json from the response" => actually it generates a `dict` - "json" is not a data type, it's a text format.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, you are absolutely right, I fixed that

Answer (score 1):

To improve on bluesummer's answer, `response.json()` is merely a shortcut for `json.loads(response.content)`, and it creates a *new* dict each time it's called. IOW what this code:

```
r1.json()['a']['a'] = 2
```

is

- create a dict from `r1.content`
- update this dict
- and finally discard it.

which is why you have to keep a reference to the dict (assign it to a variable) if you want to update it.